# Opencv error: argument -p/--prototxt is required

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

Running the code below in python 2.7 gives me this error:

usage: real_time_object_detection.py [-h] -p PROTOTXT -m MODEL [-c CONFIDENCE]
real_time_object_detection.py: error: argument -p/--prototxt is required

where real_time_object_detection.py is the name of the file im running. Any suggestions?

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.2,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

The above code is part of the code i got from here:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/18/real-time-object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/

[image: Also a screenshot might help]

Comment: you have to include arguments `-p` and `-m` when you run the code.. `python real_time_object_detection.py -p proto.txt -m /usr/guy/model.txt`

Comment: these are command line arguments right?
I guess this is how you use them (i opened powershell in the project's folder) I copy pasted your text and i get the error:
https://ibb.co/doZOPp

Answer (score 2):

The arguments prototxt and the caffemodel are present in the program file use this line to run it in the terminal.

```
python object_tracker.py --prototxt deploy.prototxt --model res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel
```